# how to restart pam.d service after changing of common-account-pc or common-auth-pc

Tags: pam

I am having trouble with a configuration line in `common-account-pc` and `common-auth-pc` that denies also root access:

```
account  required  pam_tally2.so  deny=10 onerr=fail unlock_time=600 even_deny_root root_unlock_time=5 file=/home/log/faillog
```

It seems that this line causes some problem when trying to access multiple times the SUT and i assume that it things that it is an attack via ssh.
But it is actually a test tool that tries to send several times commands via ssh root@ to the SUT (100.100.100.100) from server (10.10.10.13).

```
Apr 25 05:51:56 SUT sshd[31570]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): user root (0) tally 83, deny 10
Apr 25 05:52:16 SUT sshd[31598]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.10.10.13  user=root
Apr 25 05:52:21 SUT sshd[31568]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for root from 10.10.10.13
Apr 25 05:52:21 SUT sshd[31568]: Connection closed by 10.10.10.13 [preauth]
```

Since the password is always correct, but still after some time it starts to through exception (pexpect) Account locked.

```
version: 2.3 ($Revision: 399 $)
command: /usr/bin/ssh
args: ['/usr/bin/ssh', 'root@100.100.100.100']
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile(".*:~ #")
buffer (last 100 chars): :
Account locked due to 757 failed logins

Password:
before (last 100 chars): :
Account locked due to 757 failed logins

Password:
after: <class 'pexpect.TIMEOUT'>
...
```

But according to passwd root is not LK labeled:

```
SUT:~ # passwd -S root
root P 04/24/2017 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

Manually it is always possible to access the SUT via ssh root@!!!

So, for the moment the only that can cause this is the pam configuration. But how do i restart or activate the changes?

Does someone else have any other idea?

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 15):

There is no PAM daemon. You do not need to reload anything for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I dont think this is correct. Some changes in /etc/pam.d/sshd do not get reflected when restarting sshd service and only take effect after rebooting the machine.

Comment: Hi Basil, whic ones specifically?

Comment: I too would like to know which changes in `/etc/pam.d/sshd_config` do not get reflected when restarting the sshd service.  Per https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/pluggable-authentication-modules-pam suggest otherwise... PAM = "pluggable"

Answer (score 2):

For folks like me still finding this question:

```
sudo pam-auth-update --force --package
```

According to the man page, --package is to tell pam-auth-update that you are a maintainer script and should not be prompted interactively.

I needed to use this command to make SSH login work after editing settings in `/etc/pam.d/common-password`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are better/shorter approaches but I did a reload of my PAM auth configuration changes by running:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/pam-auth-update
```

Do not change anything in the window which'll popup and just press "Ok".

Comment: Have you an automatic way for unattented purpose ? I don't understand your -1